# GetEntityManager en Symfony 3.0.6

Tags: symfony2, symfony3

Desde la versión 3.0.6 han eliminado definitivamente (eliminado) el método getEntityManager () y ahora es getManager ().

Si está utilizando la versión 3.0.0 no tendrá problemas, pero con la versión 3.0.6 o superior Symfony se da cuenta de que cuando lo hacemos

```
$ Em = $ this-> getDoctrine () -> getEntityManager ()
```

En una acción usted debe cambiarla a esto

```
$ Em = $ this-> getDoctrine () -> getManager ();
```

Para funcionar correctamente

¿Es posible continuar usando getEntityManager () en versiones 3.0.6 o superior?

Coloque la pregunta en la versión en ingles:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41623566/getentitymanager-on-symfony-3-0-6
pero quisiera saber su criterio.

Saludos

Answer (score 2):

No. No puedes seguir usándolo.

Hay formas de mantener en uso dicho método si no quieres andar sustituyendo el nombre en todos los ficheros donde lo uses (que te recomendaría hacer esto)

Lo usual es que sobrescribas el servicio "doctrine" con tu propia clase, que hereda de la clase `Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Registry`, generar el método en cuestión y pasarlo al getManager. No obstante, no te lo recomiendo... Lo ideal es que actualices tu código y lo mantengas al día.